# How to use apply for vector with parameterized function?

Tags: r, function, apply

I have the following function

```
myfunc <- function(x,myparam) {
     x <- do_sth(x, myparam)
     plot(x)
}
```

Then to be applied to these data:

```
files <- Sys.glob("myfile_no*.txt") # This is a vector
```

Currently I do the following:

```
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
    mf <- files[i]
    myfunc(mf,myparam=3);

}
```

How can I replace the for-loop above with `apply` or its other variations?

I tried this with error:

```
> apply(x,1, myfunc, myparam)
Error in apply(files, 1, myfunc, myparam = 3) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
Execution halted
```

Comment: Why would you want to? The obvious answer is just `lapply(files, myfunc, myparam=3)` but that does not seem to make the process any clearer.... unless, of course, this is really a homework question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the obvious solution is not apply but lapply:

```
output_object <- lapply(files, myfunc, myparam = 3)
```

This also has the advantage of allowing you to use an 'anonymous' function if you want a slightly cleaner environment.

What I'm wondering, though, is why you want to? Is it an attempt to get away from perceived slowness in for loops? If so, you're not likely to see that great an improvement; people complaining "my for loop is slow" are normally complaining "I am trying a for-loop over a non-primitive data type" or "I am trying a for loop that iteratively adds to an object without a defined length". Those aren't the case here. The only thing I can think of that would improve your speed is to stop defining mf - simply call myfunc(files[i], myparam = 3).